# How can I pause in a GUI while waiting for user input?

Tags: java

I am doing a little java chatroom and I'm hitting an issue in this little bit of code. I'm not really sure how to pause the GUI from looping before the user sets an input. I have been using the commented out part of the code to pause it, but obviously I cannot have users on the GUI interacting with System.in.

```
  while(username == null)
  {
     gui.setChat("  Hello! Please enter the usename you'd like to use for the duration of the chat!\n");

     //gui.setChat("  Press Any Key To Continue...\n");
     //new java.util.Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

     username = gui.getInput();
  }
```

Comment: what is your `gui` object?

Comment: You should not explicitly **pause** GUI applications. GUI applications are usually **event driven**. Just add the required listeners to your UI components. You might want to check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html or (even better, for new projects) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm

Comment: why pause? why not just disallow posting to chat until `username != null`? just a thought

Answer (score 0):

short answer **dont pause** but if you do insist,you would have to take the multi thread approach or use JOptionPane as it blocks UI, and be careful with sleep and wake locks. here's a sample to do it

```
 JFrame frame = new JFrame(); 
            String bigList[] = new String[30];

            for (int i = 0; i < bigList.length; i++) {
              bigList[i] = Integer.toString(i);
            }

            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    frame, 
                    "Select options", 
                    "List", 
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    bigList,
                    "none");
            }
```